# Shutdown script not executing on a Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, shutdown-script

I am trying to get a shutdown script to execute using a Google Cloud compute VM.

I see this output when running `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port startup-test-v`

```
Apr  8 22:01:25 startup-test-v shutdown-script: INFO Starting shutdown scripts.
Apr  8 22:01:25 startup-test-v shutdown-script: INFO Found shutdown-script in metadata.
Apr  8 22:01:26 startup-test-v shutdown-script: INFO shutdown-script: No change requested; skipping update for [startup-test-v].
Apr  8 22:01:27 startup-test-v shutdown-script: INFO shutdown-script: Return code 0.
Apr  8 22:01:27 startup-test-v shutdown-script: INFO Finished running shutdown scripts.
```

I create the preemptible instance from the command line and shut it down in the GUI.

```
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
    --zone=$ZONE \
    --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
    --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
    --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
    --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
    --boot-disk-size=50GB \
    --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True" \
    --preemptible \
    --scopes="storage-rw,cloud-platform" \
    --metadata-from-file="shutdown-script=gce/shutdown_test.sh"
```

`shutdown_test.sh` is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "+++ Shutdown test +++"
exit 0
```

Startup scripts are working as expected. I've tried swapping the `--metadata-from-file` flag to `--metadata-from-file shutdown-script=gce/shutdown_test.sh` as well, with no change.

Ideas? It seems GCE is finding the shutdown script, but not executing it.

Comment: Might it be the case that stdout from a shutdown script doesn't make it to the serial log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that **images can overwrite the CLI-defined shutdown-script metadata**

In my case, `pytorch-latest-gpu` image changes the `shutdown-script` metadata to point at its own shutdown script. It does this during first startup.

If you edit that script - defined at `/opt/deeplearning/bin/shutdown_script.sh` - you can get whatever shutdown behavior you like. Otherwise you can edit the metadata to point at your script. Your shutdown scripts will appear in serial output logs.

```
Apr  9 23:26:46 new-test-d shutdown-script: INFO Starting shutdown scripts.
Apr  9 23:26:47 new-test-d shutdown-script: INFO Found shutdown-script in metadata.
Apr  9 23:26:47 new-test-d shutdown-script: INFO shutdown-script: ++++++++++++++ Shutdown test +++++++++++++++++
```

You can prevent the image script from changing `shutdown-script` by not giving the instance the permission to add metadata via omitting `cloud-platform` in `--scope`. Or you can edit the `shutdown-script` in the GUI after startup. You may also be able to re-edit it back via a startup script.

Comment: A good finding and surprising stuff. It shouldn't be like that. In this case the vendor has stepped into the customer area from the IaaS model perspective. Instead of using custom metadata the vendor's shutdown script should have been embedded into the image. You can create an issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown script does not provide any output neither to serial console or current SSH terminal console because it is running as root user and it's `stdout` is not routed neither to `/dev/tty*` or `/dev/ttyS*`.

To ensure that shutdown script does actually work, you might put into the VM metadata key `shutdown-script` something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash 
ofile=/var/tmp/shutdown.txt 
echo "+++ Running shutdown script +++"
echo "id = $(id)" > $ofile 
echo "script_file path = $(realpath $0)" >> $ofile 
echo "script_file rights, user, group = $(stat -c "%A %U %G" $0)" >> $ofile
```

Next connect to both the Serial Console and SSH to get ready to watch the absence of any output provided by the shutdown script.

Then stop and start the VM.

In the end you will see that shutdown script has actually worked as root user and left a log file:

```
$ ls -l /var/tmp/shutdown.txt 
 rw-r--r-- 1    root    root    165     Apr  9 18:40    shutdown.txt 
$ cat /var/tmp/shutdown.txt  
 id = uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) 
 script_file path = /tmp/metadata-scripts196132089/shutdown-script 
 script_file rights, user, group = -rwxr-xr-x root root
```

Shutdown script works for preemptible instances the same as for normal instances. The difference  is that the former have shorter [shutdown period](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/deleting-instance#delete_timeout) (30 seconds).

Comment: This approach did not work for me - `ls -l /var/tmp` would show `0 items`.

Comment: Could a custom script clean up /var/tmp/ on boot? On a default VM instance the /tmp/ directory is cleaned, but /var/tmp/ is not. You might try other destination for $ofile to check.