# Shutdown script not executing on Google Cloud VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, shutdown-script

I have the following:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3.7
f=open("python_out.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8')
f.write("OK1")
import socket
import telegram
f.write("OK2")
BOT_TOKEN = "telegram BOT_TOKEN"
CHAT_ID = "chat_id"

bot = telegram.Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
content = 'Machine name: %s is shutting down!' % host_name
bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=content)
f.write("OK3")
```

I have checked my environment, I can make this script work through `python3 script.py` when it is in the instance,It can send notifications and output `python_out.txt`.

I set this script in `shutdown-script`
[image: Screenshot]

But when I manually clicked the "stop" button, it did not work as expected. `startup-script` too.
[image: button Screenshot]

I have read many posts:

- [Shutdown script not executing on a Google Cloud VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61110921/shutdown-script-not-executing-on-a-google-cloud-vm)
- [Reliably executing shutdown scripts in Google Compute Engine](https://haggainuchi.com/shutdown.html)
- [Pro Tip: Use Shutdown Script Detect Preemption on GCP](https://blog.ceshine.net/post/gcp-shutdown-script/)

Of course it also includes official documents:

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript

I want to try setting [powerbtn.sh](https://haggainuchi.com/shutdown.html)，but i can't find `/etc/acpi/` in GCP Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

[image: etc ls Screenshot]

I can't find any more schedule, any ideas?

Comment: Can you try to write your file in `f=open("/tmp/python_out.txt",'w',encoding='utf-8')`? And tell me if it works. If so, I will explain you the issue

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is amazing! After I modify the startup-script and start it, `tmp/python_out.txt` exists, but it only prints to `print(OK1)`
https://i.imgur.com/4zoNJg7.png
https://i.imgur.com/48wACEf.png https://i.imgur.com/WH9X9Fm.png
But I am pretty sure that my environment is correct. When I enter `/usr/bin/python3.7 telegram_notification.py` in the instance connection, it can notify me via telegram, and the content of `telegram_notification.py` is the same as the startup -script same

Answer (score 1):

When you use startup script and shutdown script, the current user that execute is the `root` user, and the default directory `/root/`. This directory isn't writable, that's why nothing happens with your code.

Simply write files in writable directory and that's all.

Don't forget that the files that you create are written by the `root` user and all user can't read and/or write on file wrote by `root`. Use `chmod` or `chown` to change this.

Comment: so why can't it be notified?

Comment: Agree, it's mentioned for [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#running_a_startup_script), and by deduction, I understood that it was also the case for shut down. But, I agree, it's not clead! I opened an issue